# JMeter - "Unexpected error" - Upgraded JMeter from 2.11 to 2.13 - Unable to open test plan

Tags: plugins, jmeter

I have upgraded JMeter from 2.11 to 2.13 and have downloaded Plugins(Standard ,Extras, Extras with lib set) for 2.13 and have moved to \lib\ext” directory.

While trying to open a test plan i am getting below error in log :

2016/03/16 07:10:08 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Could not get GUI for kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector@3d92590b java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.BytesThroughputOverTimeGui
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGui(GuiPackage.java:212)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:153)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:129)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:495)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:193)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:131)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

2016/03/16 07:10:08 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:154)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:129)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:495)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:193)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:131)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: this visualizer is from http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasSet/, somehow your jmeter still doesn't "see" that package.

Comment: shall i unistall and install JMeter 2.13 again ?